# Difference between rosservice and rossrv [the info version at least]

Tags: ros

What's the difference? I see my service in `rossrv list` but not with `rosservice list`.

From [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Services)

> • rossrv: displays information about .srv data structures.
>
> • rosservice: lists and queries ROS Services

There's an abridged tree structure of the files below this text for clarity.

I have `catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/srv/GoToPosition.srv` that I see when I run

```
$ rossrv list
...
simple_arm/GoToPosition
...
```

However, my request handler is in `catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/src/arm_mover.cpp` and I only see it in rosservice list as

```
$ rosservice list
...
/arm_mover/safe_move
...
```

Why can't I see `/arm_mover/safe_move` under `rossrv list` if it is a service? And the inverse with `simple_arm/GoToPosition`?

```
$ tree
.
├── build
│   │   ├── setup.bash
│   ├── catkin_generated
│   ├── first_package
│   ├── simple_arm
│          ├── arm_mover.dir
├── devel
│   ├── include
│   │   └── simple_arm
│   │       ├── GoToPosition.h
│   │       ├── GoToPositionRequest.h
│   │       └── GoToPositionResponse.h
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── simple_arm
│   │       ├── arm_mover
│   │       └── simple_mover
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
    ├── first_package
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── package.xml
    └── simple_arm
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── config
        │   └── controllers.yaml
        ├── images
        │   └── simulation.png
        ├── launch
        │   ├── robot_control.xml
        │   ├── robot_description.xml
        │   └── robot_spawn.launch
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── meshes
        │   └── camera.dae
        ├── package.xml
        ├── README.md
        ├── src
        │   ├── arm_mover.cpp
        │   └── simple_mover.cpp
        ├── srv
        │   └── GoToPosition.srv
        ├── urdf
        │   ├── simple_arm.gazebo.xacro
        │   └── simple_arm.urdf.xacro
        └── worlds
            └── willow_garage.world
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `rossrv` is a tool for inspecting service *types*  (i.e. `.srv` files), while `rosservice` provides access to *running* services. So for example, when you call `rossrv list` it will show what service types are known in the current workspace, while `rosservice list` shows the names of the services currently running.

In your case, the service type is `simple_arm/GoToPosition` and the running service name is `/arm_mover/safe_move`, so logically the former shows up in `rossrv list` and the latter in `rosservice list`.

Another way to explain the difference between both tools is to think of `rossrv` as the service equivalent of `rosmsg`, and of `rosservice` as the service equivalent of `rostopic`. Just like `rosmsg` is concerned with message types and `rostopic` with topics to / from which messages are published / subscribed, so does `rossrv` is concerned with service types and `rosservice` with endpoints from which services can be called.

Comment: True. The `.srv` file just shows what types can go into requests and responses so it is like `rosmg`.